# How to share outside your network

Tags: windows, vpn, network-shares, remote-access

If I want to share a folder or a whole drive with people outside my network, how can i do that? Which programs should I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Hamachi](http://www.filehippo.com/download_hamachi/)** is a zero-configuration virtual private network (VPN) application capable of establishing direct links between computers that are behind NAT firewalls without requiring reconfiguration (in most cases); in other words, it establishes a connection over the Internet that very closely emulates the connection that would exist if the computers were connected over a local area network.

Comment: This is an awesome way to go. I use it a lot.   Keep in mind that there are 2 versions of Hamachi2.  There is a "web client/server" and also a small standalone executable client/server.   Make sure you choose the latter.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look at [Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com) or [SkyDrive](https://skydrive.live.com/).

They are both easy-to-use programs that will allow you to share files with multiple people.

(Not completely sure about the whole drive part, but it will definitely work on folders.)

Answer (score 0):

If you will host these from your home/work machine connected to the Internet,

- [freeSSHd](http://www.freesshd.com/) (allows FTP too)

  - will need firewall access opened for incoming FTP/SSH connections
    difficult in corporate environment
- [Opera Unite](http://unite.opera.com/)

  - will open a share path over the web!

<sub>If you are setting this up from home where you get a dialup/broadband dynamic address (just in case),

You will need to setup [DynDNS](http://www.dyndns.com/) for others to see your 'dynamic' IP address.

Or, you could talk with them and share your current IP address.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I've been playing with [bitorrent sync](http://labs.bittorrent.com/experiments/sync.html) lately - its peer to peer (IE, it just works), encrypted, and works on the two major phone OSes, linux (x86 and arm - even my raspi), and windows. All you need to do is add the folder to share, generate the secret and add it in to the other system. And since its based on bittorrent, it should handle transferring even large files gracefully

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to create a VPN and port forward. As this won't require additional software and it's cross platform.